# SSH session to computer, located behind Carrier-grade NAT and additional NAT

Tags: ssh, forwarding

I have a Server computer (Windows) with public IP address and number of Node computers (Linux), which located behind CGNAT and additional NAT with private IP addresses.
Nodes are familiar with Server IP address and its credentials.

I need to configure Nodes in the way that SSH session from Server to any Node will be possible.

I guess that SSH remote port forwarding should be used at Nodes but not sure in which way.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_. Networking is out-of-scope.

Comment: (...that said, the situation you're describing is a place where I would be setting up a VPN).